# I am getting this error after deploying to vercel - "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, express, cors

I have deployed my backend and frontend of MERN app on vercel and now i am getting this error - "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status".
I have tried everything i can from google, chatgpt and youtube but nothing worked.
Here is my vercel.json file that might help

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
      {
        "src": "*.js",
        "use": "@vercel/node"
      }
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/api/(.*)",
        "destination": "/api/$1"
      },
      {
        "source": "/(.*)",
        "destination": "/"
      }
    ],
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "/api/(.*)",
        "headers": [
          { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "value": "true" },
          { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "value": "https://snap-vault.vercel.app" },
          { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "value": "GET,OPTIONS,DELETE,POST,PUT" },
          { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "value": "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version, Authorization" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

I tried to redeploy many times, also set the "Access-control-allow-origin" to "*" and many other things also.
I tried to use the cors() middleware in server.js file but that doesn't help.
Currently i am not using this middleware.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to remove those headers from vercel.json file and use default configuration as follows

```js
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
      {
          "src": "*.js",
          "use": "@vercel/node"
      }
  ],
  "routes": [
      {
          "src": "/(.*)",
          "dest": "/"
      }
  ]
}
```

this might work. Please tell me if the issue persists.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the issue still persists

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's a common issue. I faced it as well and [this](https://github.com/vercel/vercel/issues/10927#issuecomment-1921725696) solved my issue